# Create a simple flip flop circuit

Tags: flipflop, basic, astable

I am just taking a electronics course, and i am trying to understand how to build a flip flop circuit.  I would like to build a circuit that has one push button, and one led.  Each time the push button is pressed the state of the led would change on to off or off to on.  I found this circuit http://www.josepino.com/light/led-flasher-circuits1 and i built it and it worked, but i was wondering if i could possibly adapt it to suit my purposes since it says it is similar to a flip flop.  Additionally, because i am short on supplies i would like to use only transistors, resistors, capacitors, diodes, leds, and switches in the construction of the circuit.  The only examples i can find online of a flip flop is a flip flop where a manual reset is necessary.  I believe what i currently have is an astable multivibrator, and i think what i am trying to build is a bistable multivibrator.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are taking an electronics course it would be good for you to try to figure out how the LED flasher flip-flops work. If you dive in and then have a more specific question, ask it here.

Comment: Note that flip flops are always "on", so they're generally not useful as a power switch.

Comment: i don't want to use it for a power switch, i am using it for a set of logic experiments

Comment: You "don't want to use it for a power switch"? Your question _specifically_ asks about turning an LED on and off...sounds like a power switch to me!

Comment: But i plan as using it as a way to store one bit of information in an actual application, i am just building this test circuit as a proof of concept exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a schematic for a typical T flip-flop. Every time you press the button, the output switches.

[image]

*All you need to do is to build the logic gates!* You can use diode-transistor logic, resistor-transistor logic, whatever. When you're all done, connect the inverted output (Q#) to the data pin and connect your button to the clock.

You might consider debouncing the switch. This can be achieved using a resistor and a capacitor.

Comment: -1 From the question: "i would like to use only transistors, resistors, capacitors, diodes, leds, and switches".

Comment: Exactly. Those are logic gates. You build them using RTL or DTL, like I said in the answer. Drawing out every single transistor or resistor would take a really long time...
Hass, did you even read the answer? Or just the first sentence and glanced at the picture?

Comment: I was looking for a circuit on a little bit of a simpler scale, however if this is the simplest way to accomplish this i will accept after i see the other answers.

Comment: I read your answer carefully, and I felt that you could just as easily drawn a microcontroller with a button and said "all you need to do is build a microcontroller". I feel that your answer was inappropriate given the obvious background level of the OP and the OP's interest in transistor-level circuits. By the way, given the OP's inexperience you should mention the need for a pulldown resistor on the switch...or is that also left as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: C'mon, transistor logic is even more basic than mocrocontrollers, other ICs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: DTL flip flop]

This is a flip flop I designed. It is a dtl flip flop. 1 button and 2 button versions.
Here is a link to my projects.  this flip flop was cropped out of my 3 channel amp page.
https://hackaday.io/projects/hacker/1205951
Alan Cyr